# KingFisher SwiftUI cancelOnDisappear method doesn't seem to prevent or cancel the call in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, kingfisher

I have a swiftUI app.  The app uses a scrollView LazyVGrid to present 3-photos wide by x rows.  I am using the KingFisher [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) package to download images.  The performance of the app suffers as the cancelOnDisapper doesn't seem to be called.  Thus, if the customer scrolls to the bottom of the 300+ photo list, the customer is required to wait until all 300+ photos are loaded to see the picture.

Whether I use `.cancelOnDisappear(true)` or not doesn't seem to make a difference.

It doesn't seem to matter where I put the `.cancelOnDisappear(true)` in the sequence of method calls.

I'm using the cancelOnDisappear method, but when I scroll down, every picture renders in the scrollView even if I scroll quickly.  The onSuccess and onFailure methods don't seem to be called either as I am not seeing the debug statements from those calls.

Here is a snippit of the code:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        // specifics note set yet or calculating sale summary
        if (!seriesList.isSpecificsListSet  || isCalculatingSaleSummary) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ProgressView("Loading...")
                    .scaleEffect(3, anchor: .center)
                    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .red))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
                           height: geometry.size.height)
                    .zIndex(1)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0,
                    maxWidth: .infinity,
                    minHeight: 0,
                    maxHeight: .infinity,
                    alignment: .topLeading
            ).background(Color(.systemGray5))
            .opacity(0.75)
            .zIndex(1)
        }
        if isShowPhotos {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Text(kNewText)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            Text(kLooseText)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack(spacing: 6) {
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .have, filterValue: $new_HaveShow)
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .want, filterValue: $new_WantShow)
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .sell, filterValue: $new_SellShow)
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .order, filterValue: $new_OrderShow)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            HStack(spacing: 6) {
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .have, filterValue: $loose_HaveShow)
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .want, filterValue: $loose_WantShow)
                                filterSwitch(specificsTypeTextEnum: .sell, filterValue: $loose_SellShow)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    } // hstack filter switches

                    SearchBar(searchText: $searchText, isSearching: $isSearching)
                    
                    // beginning photos
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [
                    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100), spacing: 8, alignment: .top),
                    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100), spacing: 8, alignment: .top),
                    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100), spacing: 8)
                    ], alignment: .leading, spacing: 9, content: {
                        switch showContextType {
                        case .series:
                            ForEach(showFigures
                                        .filter({(
                                                $0.seriesUniqueId == series.uniqueId && $0.searchString.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
                                                || ($0.seriesUniqueId == series.uniqueId && searchText.isEmpty)}),
                                    id: \.self)
                            { figure in
                                FigurePhoto(figure: figure, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh)
                            }
                        case .whatIsNew:
                            ForEach(showFigures
                                        .filter({
                                                ($0.addedDate > isNewAddedDate
                                                    && $0.searchString.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
                                                || ($0.addedDate > isNewAddedDate && searchText.isEmpty)})
                                        .sorted(by: {$0.addedDate == $1.addedDate ? $0.figurePackageName < $1.figurePackageName : $0.addedDate > $1.addedDate}),
                                    id: \.self)
                            { figure in
                                FigurePhoto(figure: figure, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh)
                            }
                        case .allFigures:
                            ForEach(showFigures
                                        .filter({
                                                ($0.searchString.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
                                                || (searchText.isEmpty)})
                                        .sorted(by: {$0.figurePackageName < $1.figurePackageName}),
                                    id: \.self)
                            { figure in
                                FigurePhoto(figure: figure, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh)
                            }
                        } // end showContent type switch
                    }) // end alignment & lazy grid
                } // end list view
                BannerVC().frame(width: 320, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            } // end vstack
            .navigationBarTitle(series.seriesName)
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: FigureListMenuItems(series: series,
                                              showContextType: showContextType,
                                              filterByPhase: $filterByPhase,
                                              isShowPhotos: $isShowPhotos,
                                              isCalculatingSaleSummary: $isCalculatingSaleSummary)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the loaded photos

```
struct FigurePhoto: View {
@ObservedObject var figure: Figure
@Binding var needsRefresh: Bool

var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(
        destination: FigureDetailView(figure: figure, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh)) {
    
        // name photo and specifics
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
            // image and specifics
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4) {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    let image = figure.flickrPhotoString ?? ""
                    KFImage(URL(string: image))
                        .resizable()
                        .onSuccess { r in
                                #if DEBUG
                                print("success: \(r)")
                                #endif
                        }
                        .onFailure { error in
                            #if DEBUG
                            print("ERROR:  Failure in KFImage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            #endif
                        }
                        .placeholder {
                            // Placeholder while downloading.
                            kMyToyBoxLogoImage
                                .resizable()
                                .opacity(0.3)
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .cornerRadius(22)
                        }
                        .cancelOnDisappear(true) // cancel if scrolled past
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(22)
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    VStack {
                                        
                                        if figure.isSpecificsSet {
                                            SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .have,
                                                                  newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_haveCount,
                                                                  looseCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.loose_haveCount)
                                            SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .want,
                                                                  newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_wantCount,
                                                                  looseCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.loose_wantCount)
                                            SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .sell,
                                                                  newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_sellCount,
                                                                  looseCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.loose_sellCount)
                                            SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .order,
                                                                  newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_orderCount,
                                                                  looseCount: 0)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/6)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            , alignment: .bottom)
                    Text(figure.figurePackageName)
                        .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .semibold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.top, 4)
                    // convert to strings to avoid commas
                    Text(figure.series.seriesName)
                        .font(.system(size: 9, weight: .regular))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    Spacer()
                } // end vstack
                .onAppear() {
                    // primary front image use global unique id to avoid random matching numbers _small
                    figure.fetchFigureImageURL(withTags: figure.figureGlobalUniqueId, withText: "\(figure.figureGlobalUniqueId)\(kPrimaryFrontImageNameSuffix)\(kSmallSuffix)")
                } // end vstack on appear
            } // end hstack
        } // end vstack
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
        )
    } // end navigation link
} // end body
}
```

Comment: Try to move it out of `NavigationLink` label. Eg., make link as overlay of `KFImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @Asperi I moved the NavigationLink to an overlay.  The performance is significantly improved and the `.cancelOnDisappear(true)` is functioning.

```
        .overlay(
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: FigureDetailView(figure: figure, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh)) {
                        Rectangle()
                            .hidden()
                }
            }
        )
```

Here is the full structure code for the PhotoView.  I'm not sure if my implementation is ideal.

```
struct FigurePhoto: View {
  @ObservedObject var figure: Figure
  @Binding var needsRefresh: Bool

  var body: some View {
    
    // name photo and specifics
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
        // image and specifics
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                let image = figure.flickrPhotoString ?? ""
                KFImage(URL(string: image))
                    .resizable()
                    .onSuccess { r in
                            #if DEBUG
                            print("success: \(r)")
                            #endif
                    }
                    .onFailure { error in
                        #if DEBUG
                        print("ERROR:  Failure in KFImage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        #endif
                    }
                    .placeholder {
                        // Placeholder while downloading.
                        kMyToyBoxLogoImage
                            .resizable()
                            .opacity(0.3)
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .cornerRadius(22)
                    }
                    .cancelOnDisappear(true) // cancel if scrolled past
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .cornerRadius(22)
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                VStack {
                                    
                                    if figure.isSpecificsSet {
                                        SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .have,
                                                              newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_haveCount,
                                                              looseCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.loose_haveCount)
                                        SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .want,
                                                              newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_wantCount,
                                                              looseCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.loose_wantCount)
                                        SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .sell,
                                                              newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_sellCount,
                                                              looseCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.loose_sellCount)
                                        SpecificsImageOverlay(specificsType: .order,
                                                              newCount: figure.publishedSpecifics.new_orderCount,
                                                              looseCount: 0)
                                    }
                                }
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width/6)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        , alignment: .bottom)
                Text(figure.figurePackageName)
                    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .semibold))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .padding(.top, 4)
                // convert to strings to avoid commas
                Text(figure.series.seriesName)
                    .font(.system(size: 9, weight: .regular))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                Spacer()
            } // end vstack
            .onAppear() {
                // primary front image use global unique id to avoid random matching numbers _small
                figure.fetchFigureImageURL(withTags: figure.figureGlobalUniqueId, withText: "\(figure.figureGlobalUniqueId)\(kPrimaryFrontImageNameSuffix)\(kSmallSuffix)")
            } // end vstack on appear
        } // end hstack
    } // end vstack
    .overlay(
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
            NavigationLink(
                destination: FigureDetailView(figure: figure, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh)) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .hidden()
            }
        }
    )
} // end body
}
```